# Interact with Sharepoint 2010 Workflows without Sharepoint objects

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation

What I'm trying to do is to write a process that interacts with a workflow running inside of Sharepoint 2010, but not using Sharepoint's objects or lists.

The reason I want to do it like this, is because I'm thinking of reusing this process to work with regular Windows Workflow Foundation workflows (If it's possible)

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint utilize WorkflowRuntime internally but it's not possible to access it using standard Workflow runtime methods. But you can use SharePoint classes and objects outside SharePoint e.g. your application running on SharePoint server.